# css to make footer top line curved inward with using position fixed only

Tags: html, css, footer

I am building a html page where the footer is position fixed.
I want to create this footer top border line to be curved inward.
But I'm failing to do this without using position relative for my footer and using pseudo-element as position absolute.
The rounded inward edge must look elegant as it is going to a fixed footer.

**Example of my idea is the photo below.**
[image: curved top border footer]

**This is the css for my footer currently.**

```
footer {
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 15px 10px rgba(146, 143, 143, 0.149);
  background-color: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.15); 
}
```

The footer should work as position fixed after changing it to my desired idea.

Comment: Can you provide more of the code or a reproducible example? Can't see the pseudo element to test it out